# redgate database dependencies

Tags: git, repository, tfsbuild, redgate

I'm new to Redgate and looking for some help on how best to setup my database repository.

I have multiple sites and multiple databases, they all have their own repositories. A database can be associated with one or more sites.

I've created my repositories in the following way;

```
wwwroot/webapps/site1
wwwroot/webapps/site2
wwwroot/webapps/site3

wwwroot/databases/db1
wwwroot/databases/db2
wwwroot/databases/db3
wwwroot/databases/db4
```

For example, site1,2,3 all use db1 but site2 is also associated with db2. The changes that happen against db1 apply to all the sites but I want to be able to check in my changes to db1 irrespective of which site repository I'm working on.

All this works just fine when creating builds to each individual repository but I want to deploy my code and db changes as part of the same build.

At the moment, I have a TFS builds (TFS 2015 and using task based build) that deploy my code and I have to make sure any associated DB changes are deployed separately as part of another build.

Is it possible to somehow link my code build to a database change have them deploy together? Is my repository setup correct or is there a better way to set this up? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

More info to describe my issue.

```
    Code repository
wwwroot/webapps/site1/feature_A
wwwroot/webapps/site1/feature_B
wwwroot/webapps/site2/feature_C

    DB repository
wwwroot/databases/db1/feature_A
wwwroot/databases/db1/feature_C
```

Using the above example;

feature_A (code repository) is dependent on feature_A (DB repository). The current setup will require me to create two build one for my Code and the other for my DB.

feature_B (code repository) has no dependencies

feature_C (code repository) is dependent on feature_C (DB repository).

I can only create a build by specifying a feature, as my Code and DB repositories are separate I'm forced to do this in two builds.

I would like to achieve the above by creating one build that will push my DB and Code changes out at the same time. I don't know how best to do this or if it's possible. If it's not possible can someone suggest an alternative.

I would not like to add the DB repository inside my web folder because the same database is used across multiple websites and this will cause problems.

For example the following will work for me but it means the DB1 repository will be created multiple times.

```
wwwroot/webapps/site1\Code\
wwwroot/webapps/site1\DB1\

wwwroot/webapps/site2\Code\
wwwroot/webapps/site2\DB1\
wwwroot/webapps/site2\DB2\

wwwroot/webapps/site3\Code\
wwwroot/webapps/site3\DB1\
```

Comment: Can't you just have a second build task/step as part of your TFS build that deploys the database? It doesn't need to be a completely separate build.

Comment: Do you mean you want to trigger a TFS build when there is a change in database? Which version of TFS are you using? Do you use XAML build or tasks based build?

Comment: @David - I can't do what you suggested as the build has to point to a feature. As the code and database repos are separate I can't include the another point the build at 2nd repo.

Comment: @Cece - I'm using TFS 2015 and task based build. I don't want to trigger a TFS build, what I would like to do is be able to create a feature in my code repo and the same feature in my db repo and when I create a build somehow include the features from the code and db repo together. I don't if that can be done so I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: How is a feature defined? Is it by changeset or by work item?

Comment: Not sure when you mean by changeset or working item, I've setup my source control in Redgate to point to my DB Git repository. So a when a change is made it appears in my Git repository under my checked out Git feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to get two repository in one build. You can check the steps below:

1. In the build definition, specify one repository:

[image]

2. Then add a command line task to use git command to clone another repository to the same location as step 1:

[image]

If there is authorization issue when you clone repository, enable "Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token":

[image]

Comment: This is probably the best/only solution that's been suggested however it's still not exactly what I was hoping for. Setting up my build in this way is fine but it means before running a build I'll have to update the build configuration and change the feature the command line agent step is pointing to or remove it if it's not required. I just want to be able to queue a build without having to change the build configuration every time

Comment: That's the only way to get two repo in a build currently. If the command line is not required, you can disable it in your build definition. When you need it, enable it.